# My QFileSystemModel only sees one drive. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I've tried almost everything I can think of, but I'm beginning to think I am missing something major. Do I need to create a different QFileSystemModel for each 'disk' connected to my system? If I do, how do I get the list of connected devices?

Here is the code I have so far...

```
class FolderSelectDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, startingFolderName, parent = ZipRenamer):
        super(FolderSelectDialog, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('rootSelectDialog.ui', self)
        fileModel = QFileSystemModel()
        fileModel.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.Hidden | QDir.AllEntries | QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
        fileModel.setRootPath(startingFolderName)
        self.selectedPath = startingFolderName
        self.fileSelectTreeView.setModel(fileModel)
        self.fileSelectTreeView.setCurrentIndex(fileModel.index(startingFolderName))
        self.fileSelectTreeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        self.fileSelectTreeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.fileDoubleClickedHandler)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.cancelClickedHandler)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.okayClickedHandler)
        self.fileSelectTreeView.clicked.connect(self.selectionChangedHandler)
        self.fileSelectTreeView.expanded.connect(self.itemExpandedHandler)
```

Comment: I'd start by removing that `setFilter()`.

Comment: Yea, tried that. I also tried lots of filter combinations.
I probably should have mentioned that this is running under MacOS, not MSWindows.

Comment: @Arana There's no such thing as a "drive" on unix. All you have is a single filesystem which may include additoonal mount-points without pre-determined locations. A mount-point isn't equivalent to a "drive", since it can repressent many different things - e.g. a network share, loop device, bind mount, tmp fs, fuse fs, etc. Qt provides the [QStorageInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html) class for listing mounted storage devices (and Windows drives), but it could prove quite tricky to interpret its output consistently for all system configurations.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, as a **nix guy, I'm aware of that, but Apple does fake that look. I am just trying to make the View look familiar to a user that *isn't* aware of that.

Comment: Having just built this on Windows 10 and seen it present differently, it must be more of a 'presentation' issue under MacOS, since all of the 'drives' ARE available under the /Volumes folder. If I can get it to look like the standard drive view. Thanks to @ekhumoro, for pointing me to QStorageInfo class. Maybe I can make use of this to straighten out the presentation of the filesystem.